# How to make a swf file play only once per session / visit?

Tags: flash

I have a flash logo on my website but I don't want it to play every page load.

I'm a total newbie in actionscript but I've gone as far as I have with the logo by googling and asking questions. I hope someone can please tell me how to do this one last thing I need on my logo since I can't find it anywhere! :)

I'm using AS2 but I guess I can use 3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SharedObject` to remember a visit to your SWF.

Here's what you need in ActionScript 2:

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("someName");

if(!so.data.visited)
{
    so.data.visited = true;

    // Do something for first visit.
    //
}
else
{
    // Do something else for subsequent visits.
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the logo to play if, say, the user is inactive for 10 minutes or closes his browser and returns later that day.. How would I go by doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by typing `stop();` in the actionscript panel of the last frame of the movie.